# EditorJS is not showing in NextJS even it is loaded through SSR:false

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering, editorjs

so I am integrating EditorJs with the NextJs  app I have done the initialization in the console it shows Editojs is ready but on the screen, it is not visible

can anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong I am sharing my code below

Editor.js

```
import { createReactEditorJS } from 'react-editor-js'
import { EditorTools } from './EditorTools'; 
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'


const Editor = () => {

    const ReactEditorJS = createReactEditorJS();
    return (
        <div>
            <ReactEditorJS holder="customEditor" tools={EditorTools}>
                <div id="customEditor" />
            </ReactEditorJS>
        </div>
    )

}

export default Editor
```

EditorTools.js

```
import Header from '@editorjs/header';

export const EditorTools = {
  header: {
    class: Header,
    config: {
      placeholder: 'Let`s write an awesome story! ✨',
    },
  },
};
```

Create.js

```
import React from 'react'
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';

const EditorJSNoSSRWrapper = dynamic(import('../../../components/Editor/Editor'), {
  ssr: false,
  loading: () => <p>Loading ...</p>,
});

const create = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <EditorJSNoSSRWrapper  />
    </div>
  )
}

export default create
```

Comment: Did you find an answer to this?